# ServiceM8 create new job via API

Tags: php

I'm sending the following JSON to the SM8 API
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job.json

The response I am getting is `200 OK`, & the job is being created in my servicem8 dashboard, but the name and description fields are not being populated for some reason.

Also, I was hoping to capture the newly created job ID from the response object, but it is either not being returned or I am unsure how to access it.

Here's the JSON that I'm passing to the API:

```
{
    "status":"Quote",
    "job_address":"123 Street Lane, , London, SE2",
    "description":"Remove & replace existing carpets",
    "contact_first":"Joe",
    "contact_last":"Bloggs"
}
```

Anyone see what the problem is?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID of newly created records is returned in a HTTP header called `x-record-uuid` when you initially create the record.

The description is not being populated because the field name needs to be `job_description` (rather than `description`).

Contact details for jobs need to be populated through the JobContacts endpoint (http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/reference/jobcontact-3/). `contact_first` and `contact_last` aren't valid field names for Job objects.

So for your example record you will need to do the following:

1. POST your job details (status, job_address, job_description) to the Job endpoint
2. Inspect the x-record-uuid header to determine the UUID of the job you just created
3. POST another request to the JobContact endpoint to create a contact for the job. Set the job_uuid to the UUID of the job that was created. You will probably want to set type=JOB and is_primary_contact=1. It will look something like this:

   ```
   {
       "first":"Joe",
       "last":"Bloggs",
       "job_uuid":"7d97be49-0eff-417a-8251-ab8b8942d65b",
       "type":"JOB",
       "is_primary_contact":1
   }
   ```

Comment: Any chance of merging those two api endpoints? Seems simpler.